# Odd drywall bulges and ripples, not on seams

Tags: drywall, repair, patching-drywall

Does anyone know what caused this?  I would like to know what to expect before I try to sand or cut it out to repair it. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DiY! What kind of covering material are we looking at here? Is it something elastic or something like spackle? And what's directly behind the drywall pane?

Comment: What's the wall construction?  (Drwyall, plaster on brick,  Plaster on lath, etc)

Comment: It is a standard stud wall with 16" spacing, and regular drywall as far as I can tell. The neighbors tell me the prev owners were "Do-it-your-selfer's", and I am finding many areas of cut corners. The shapes are just so odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody applied plaster to the wall (probably when fixing holes) and didn't do a good job of smoothing it. The waves were caused by the putty knife moving back and forth when it was being passed over the plaster; maybe due to a shaking hand, maybe lumps in the plaster. Getting a smooth finish on a wall is harder than it looks, and if someone's in a hurry, they might not bother.

If the wall feels solid, there's no need to cut anything out. Sand it (preferably with a sanding screen) to knock down the high spots. That will probably be enough to make it flat, but if there are any depressions, fill them with plaster and smooth with a wide putty knife. Then prime and paint.

Or just hang a picture over it.

Comment: More likely joint compound, but yeah.

Comment: I like the hang a picture option, but before prime/paint, you should hit the area with a light application of orange peel texture from a can. Go really wide.